# How to add conditional formatting to my existing VB code in. MS Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a table in MS Word comprising of dropdown list items as well as columns that display and output values depending on the combination of selected dropdown list items. I am trying to have the result cells filled in colours depending on their contents. Eg. anything starting with >=70 to be coloured red.

How would I go about doing this?

I know this should be done in Excel but I have to work with what I've got, sadly.

I tried using a Macro and did get my colours to change, however my existing VB code (listed below then stopped working).

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal CC As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim CField As String, LField As String, RField As String, CText As String, LText As String, CRate As Double, LRate As Double, RRate As Double, RCat As String, RCatField As String
Select Case CC.Title
Case "C1", "L1"
CField = "C1"
LField = "L1"
RField = "R1"
RCatField = "RR1"

Case "C2", "L2"
CField = "C2"
LField = "L2"
RField = "R2"
RCatField = "RR2"




Case Else
Exit Sub
End Select

CText = Left(ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle(CField).Item(1).Range.Text, 1)
LText = Left(ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle(LField).Item(1).Range.Text, 1)
    If Not IsNumeric(CText) Then
With ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle(RField)(1)
   .LockContents = False
   .Range.Text = ""
   .LockContents = True
End With
With ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle(RCatField)(1)
   .LockContents = False
   .Range.Text = ""
   .LockContents = True
End With
      End If
        If Not IsNumeric(LText) Then
      Exit Sub
      End If
      LRate = LText
      CRate = CText
      RRate = ((CRate * 3) + (LRate * 2)) * 4
      Select Case RRate
      Case Is < 41
      RCat = "Low"
      Case Is < 55
      RCat = "Moderate"
      Case Is < 70
      RCat = "High"
      Case Is >= 70
        RCat = "Catastrophic"
      End Select




With ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle(RField)(1)
   .LockContents = False
   .Range.Text = RRate
   .LockContents = True
End With
With ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle(RCatField)(1)
   .LockContents = False
   .Range.Text = RCat
   .LockContents = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If you need to address someone in comments use the @ symbol, for example @macropod. Since you placed your comment to macropod under the other Answer, without a @, Paul won't see your question concerning his answer... Also, when you have additional information about your problem, please use the [edit] link to append it directly to the question - it gets lost in comments, especially in a comment to an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
With ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle(RCatField)(1)
  .LockContents = False
  .Range.Text = RCat
  With .Range.Cells(1).Shading
    Select Case RCat
      Case "Low": .BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorBrightGreen
      Case "Moderate": .BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorYellow
      Case "High": .BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorOrange
      Case "Catastrophic":: .BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorRed
      Case Else: .BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
    End Select
  End With
  .LockContents = True
End With
```

Comment: The OP wrote a comment to you in response to a now-removed "answer": I am getting the following error message: macropod Run-time error '4605' This method or property is not available because the current selection is locked for format changes. It happens at this line: Case "Low": .BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorBrightGreen

Comment: @exceloverflow123: An error of that kind suggests you have another content control in the cell and that content control is locked to prevent editing.